# using the mix() helper in a bladeview inside a conditional giving errors

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-mix

I just installed laravel 5.5 and the good news is, I finally managed to get npm run dev/production working. The manifest file looks fine too. In my bladeview I am using these lines:

```
@if($userIsLoggedIn)
    <link href="{{ mix('build/ccs/admin.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
@else
    <link href="{{ mix('build/ccs/auth.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
@endif
```

But loading the page results in the following error:

[image]

So I was like, lets go into the mix helper and dump some data to see what it looks like... :

```
dd($manifest, $path);  gives :
```

[image: mix dump]

Is it just me, or does the index actualy exists? using

```
dd($manifest[$path]);
```

actualy results in Undefined index. The weirdest thing, when I write the link outside of the  conditional like this:

```
<link href="{{ mix('build/css/auth.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Styles -->
{{-- @if($userIsLoggedIn)
    <link href="{{ mix('build/ccs/admin.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
@else
    <link href="{{ mix('build/ccs/auth.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
@endif --}}
```

then if all works fine! no errors or undefined indexes whatsoever, versioning/non versioning.. all loads :P There is some stuff going on here that I don't understand.. Any1 has any ideas??

EDIT::

Using these lines at the bottom of the body  works fine too..

```
@if($userIsLoggedIn)
    <script src="{{ mix('/build/js/admin.js') }}"></script>
@endif
```

Comment: Because of total stupidity, I am not even gonna give myself the credit of solving this...took me about 4+ hours to see it.  the string says 'ccs', not 'css'.. Anyone who answers this first will get the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

)) try  to change way of css files) 
`mix('build/ccs/admin.css')` => `mix('build/css/admin.css')`
etc.)

Answer (score 1):

It should be 'build/**css**/admin.css' instead of build/**ccs**/admin.css.